Sinon spy fails to register call
Can someone assist me in understanding why sinon spy calls are fail to register?
Running the following test, results in failure:
"use strict";

const sinon = require("sinon");
const proxyquire = require("proxyquire");

const getFunctions = (sqsMock) =>
  proxyquire("../index.js", { "@third-party/mv-sqs": sqsMock });

const getHandler = function (stub) {
  return function (...args) {
    console.log("Args:", args);
    stub.call(stub, ...args);
  };
};

const getQueueTemplateMock = function GetQueueTemplateMock(name, options) {
  const { sql, redis, logger, handler = () => {}, queueConfig = {} } = options;

  return {
    name,
    setup: async function (_config) {
      return { handler, queueConfig, logger, sql, redis };
    },
  };
};

describe("listenOnAllQueues", () => {
  let sqsSpy = null;
  const loggerMock = { info: () => {} };
  const sqsMock = {
    receive: (_q, _handler, _options) => {
      console.log("Receive function has been called--");
      return "";
    },
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    sinon.reset();
    sinon.restore();
    sqsSpy = sinon.spy(sqsMock);
  });

  it("usage", () => {
    const handlerStub = sinon.stub();
    const handlerMock = getHandler(handlerStub);
    const { listenOnAllQueues } = getFunctions(sqsMock);
    const dependencies = { logger: loggerMock };
    const queues = [
      getQueueTemplateMock("testTemplate", {
        ...dependencies,
        handler: handlerMock,
      }),
    ];

    listenOnAllQueues({}, loggerMock, queues);

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(sqsSpy.receive);
  });
});

Test Console Output:
Args: [
  {
    logger: { info: [Function: info] },
    sql: undefined,
    redis: undefined
  }
]
Receive function has been called--

1) listenOnAllQueues
       usage:
     AssertError: expected receive to be called once but was called 0 times

Code:
'use strict';

const {map} = require('ramda');
const sqs = require('@third-party/mv-sqs');

const _getSqsOptions = function getSqsOptions(logger) {
  return {
    retries: 4,
    resolveEachBatch: true,
    maxNumberOfMessages: 4,
    log: logger.info.bind(logger)
  };
};

const listenOnAllQueues = function ListenOnAllQueues(config, logger, queues) {
  return map(async ({name, setup}) => {
    const configuration = await setup(config).catch(err => {
      logger.error(`Error loading configuration for ${name} queue`);
      logger.error(err);
      throw err;
    });

    const {queueConfig, handler, ...dependencies} = configuration;
    return sqs.receive(queueConfig, handler(dependencies), _getSqsOptions(configuration.logger));
  }, queues);
};

module.exports = {listenOnAllQueues};

The previous questions were of small assistance:

Why is this sinon spy not being called
Sinon spy fails even though function spied on is being called

I have spent an entire day on this, any idea what I have overlooked?

I figured it out, massive facepalm moment.
I removed the use of Ramda's map function. It seems to mess up sinon's indirection.
Here is my updated code:
'use strict';

const sqs = require('@third-party/mv-sqs');

const _getSqsOptions = function getSqsOptions(logger) {
  return {
    retries: 4,
    resolveEachBatch: true,
    maxNumberOfMessages: 4,
    log: logger.info.bind(logger)
  };
};

const listenOnAllQueues = async function ListenOnAllQueues(config, logger, queues) {
  for (let {name, setup} of queues) {
    const configuration = await setup(config).catch(err => {
      logger.error(`Error loading configuration for ${name} queue`);
      logger.error(err);
      throw err;
    });

    const {queueConfig, handler, ...dependencies} = configuration;
    sqs.receive(queueConfig, handler(dependencies), _getSqsOptions(configuration.logger));
  }
};

module.exports = {listenOnAllQueues};

